# TXT into filtered CSV

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I'm building a small application that intends to simplify the information displayed in a .txt file and display in Excel (.CSV).

I've already got the information to a String and I'm planning to use the CSVExport library available in Nugget to build the excel file. The thing is that I need to filter and treat the information.
The data has the following format:

```
 0001. 001.0001.  01.   3.  17.  07.  13.  12.  02.0002.V TT.    .MTC1.
75.39.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.
00.00.00.00.00.00.00.16.
```

I intend to isolate the first line (Header), keep its values, formulate a cell called "Controller" -> "MTC1" , Date of the first collect " 13.07.2017 - 14.00h", "Type" -> " TT"

For the rest of the information, I intend to put each data "75","39","00"... in a cell for every 5 minutes after the first collect, per cell.

```
Controller  MTC1

Type        TT

Start 20/10/2016 15:45

20/10/2016  15:45   52  
            15:50   50
            15:55   00
            16:00   00
```

...

My issue is the method that I'm going to use to filtrate the information.
I've been researching some methods to do so but due to my lack of experience I just can't seem to chose the right one. Build a list, StringBuffer...

Here's what I've done up to now:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CsvExport myExport = new CsvExport();
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            int first=0;
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            {
                String line = "";
                string[] Results = new string[500];
                String filepath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
                int i = 0;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Results[i] += line;
                    i++;
                }

                Console.Write(Results[0]); 
                string csvpath = "C:\\counts.csv";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, having this format of file, how would you filter the values for the table?

Thanks.

Comment: Unclear what you want to do. You have a csv and you are reading it and then you want to filter? Don't you know the columns already?

Comment: Could you add an example of desired output file format?

Comment: I have updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at `Split` method ([msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)). You can use it like this:

```
var sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
string[] header = null;
while (true)
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();
    if (line == null)
        break; // End of file

    var lineParts = line.Split(" .".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (header == null)
    {
        // save first line
        header = lineParts;
        // now header[13] is equal "MTC1"
    }
    else
    {
        // process other lines by one
    }
}
```

`StringBuilder` is helpful if you need to build a string in memory. In your case it's seems that you rather need a `StreamWriter` object.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great help.

Comment: @kohhworlwide Please see [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). If answer is helpful you can upvote it, otherwise downvote. This will help other users to find good answers